# NodeJS Express SSL not working with Bitnami EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am running my Bitnami Amazon EC2 VPC App via NodeJS using Express (Apache is disabled) and am having trouble getting SSL to work. I have implemented SSL using this implementation: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ssl-root-cas.  I purchased the SSL Certificate from Symantec. The app runs HTTP/S servers on ports 8080/8443 and I port forward each to 80/443.  The app is run via `nohup`. I have enabled inbound/outbound https traffic in my security group on EC2.

Here is the sample implementation:

```
require("ssl-root-cas/latest")
  .inject()
  .addFile(__dirname + "/ssl/IntermediateCA.cer")
  .addFile(__dirname + "/ssl/crossRootCA.cer");

var server = {
  http: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080
  },
  https: {
    port: 8443,
    options: {
      key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/server.key"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/ssl_certificate.cer")
    }
  }
};

https.createServer(server.https.options, app).listen(server.https.port);
http.createServer(app).listen(server.http.port);
```

For whatever reason, SSL is still not working.  Suggestions??

Comment: You should explain exactly what happens and doesn't happen. "still not working" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Running a ```netstat -a``` does show a connection listening on 8443

Comment: This is how I forwarded the ports too 

```sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080``` and 


```sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm running into the same issues.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. What was the solution?